# Encoding problem in python3 with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I have strange problem in **scraping** a unicode page in selenium python.
i am sharing the full code, the code is giving me wrong encoding. i tried almost every thing but no success so far, any help will be so appreciated.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import time


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
#options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'pt,pt_BR'})

chrome_path = '/var/www/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path,  options=options)
driver.get("http://www.correios.com.br/solucoes-empresariais/correios-facil")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
a = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("p")
for i in a:
    s = i.text
    #s = s.encode("UTF-8")
    print(s)

driver.quit()
```

In output i am getting Wrong encoding like below

Com as soluÃ§Ãµes de um grande operador logÃ­stico, a sua empresa pode se destacar e crescer ainda mais. FortaleÃ§a seu negÃ³cio, tornando-se um parceiro dos Correios.
Com o CartÃ£o Correios FÃ¡cil vocÃª terÃ¡ acesso Ã  vantagens exclusivas, preÃ§os diferenciados, ferramentas gratuitas e pagamento a prazo.
Adquira agora o seu CartÃ£o Correios FÃ¡cil. Com ele vocÃª poderÃ¡ utilizar os serviÃ§os: Encomendas, Carta Comercial, Impresso, *CorreiosLog+, CertificaÃ§Ã£o Digital, **Produtos.
AtenÃ§Ã£o! VocÃª vai precisar do seu certificado digital (e-CNPJ). Caso nÃ£o possua, clique aqui.
Se sua empresa ou o Ã³rgÃ£o pÃºblico que vocÃª representa, ainda nÃ£o possui contrato com os Correios, ou se jÃ¡ possui e deseja ter acesso a outros serviÃ§os e condiÃ§Ãµes ainda mais vantajosas, utilize a modalidade abaixo, atravÃ©s do Sistema EletrÃ´nico de InformaÃ§Ãµes â SEI:
Para te ajudar, criamos o seguinte passo a passo
Caso vocÃª queira ir direto para a pÃ¡gina do SEI, clique aqui
Em caso de dÃºvidas, entre em contato com nossa Central de Atendimento pelo telefone 3003-0800.
*Para comeÃ§ar a utilizar o serviÃ§o de logÃ­stica â CorreiosLog+, preencher o formulÃ¡rio http://www2.correios.com.br/servicos/falecomoscorreios/cliente_contrato.cfm para atendimento comercial.
**Sujeito Ã  disponibilidade.
âClique aqui e conheÃ§a os Termos e Anexos dos ServiÃ§os contratados.â

Answer (score 0):

Check your system encoding:

```
import sys
import locale

print(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
print(locale.getpreferredencoding())
```

Most probably it's not UTF-8.
So you have to change it in:

`sudo nano /etc/default/locale`

Use `locale -a` to get the list of available locales.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    test = ' RelÃ³gio feminino dourado '
    label =  test.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
```

More info on encodings: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: giving error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 1: invalid continuation byte

Comment: See my edit answer. Also if you can provide the code where you're getting the label will be useful

Comment: still error dear >>> test = ' RelÃ³gio feminino dourado '
>>> label =  test.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 4: invalid continuation byte

Comment: i am scrapping data from Portuguese website using selenium

Comment: What are you doing with the label string? This may be an issue with the Python encoding environment variable (if you are sending this to the stdout), if you're writing this to a file you can set the encoding for the output file or in the for loop, maybe getting the text with a.text.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8') solves this.

Comment: No i am not writing to file, i am writing to database and also printing on screen, btw label is the test variable here, in original code variable name is different

Comment: whenever i use .decode('utf-8')  .. it throws error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 4: invalid continuation byte